# Growth of the set $\lbrace 2^n+3^m \rbrace$ in the integers

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $A=\lbrace 2^n+3^m \ | \ n,m\in{\mathbb N}\rbrace$, and denote by $a_k$ the $k$-th element of $A$ in order from smallest to greatest ; thus $a_1=2,a_2=3,a_3=4,a_4=5,a_5=7\ldots$. Is it known whether $\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}$ has a limit when $k\to\infty$ ?

Weaker question : is it true that $\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k} \leq \frac{3}{2}$ for every $k$ ? I have checked this for $k\leq 1500$.

My thoughts : if we write $a_k=2^n+3^m$, then $a_k<2^{n+1}+3^m$ so $a_{k+1} \leq 2^{n+1}+3^m \leq 2a_k$, so if the limit exists it is $\leq 2$. Numerical evidence suggests that the $\liminf$ is $1$.

Comment: Presumably, the $k$th element is the $k$th element in order from smallest to greatest?

Comment: By $a_k$ are you referring to the $k^{\text{th}}$ element of $A$ under the usual ordering on $\mathbb{N}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that 
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2^n + 3^{m+1}}{2^n + 3^m} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1 + \frac{3^{m+1}}{2^n}}{1 + \frac{3^m}{2^n}} = 1
$$
Thus, we may conclude that each element $a_k$ is part of a subsequence $\{a_{k_1},a_{k_2}, \dots\}$ in which 
$$
\frac{a_{k_{j + 1}}}{a_{k_j}} \to 1
$$
From this, we may conclude that $a_{k+1}/a_k \to 1$ as desired.  In particular, take $k(j)$ to mean $k_j$, and recall that the $\{a_k\}$ form an increasing sequence.  Note, then, that for any $a_i$ in the stretch $\{a_{k(j)},a_{k(j)+1}, \dots, a_{k(j+1) - 1}\}$, we have
$$
\frac{a_{i+1}}{a_i} \leq \frac{a_{k(j+1)}}{a_{k(j)}}
$$
it follows that $\limsup_{i \to \infty} \frac{a_i}{a_{i+1}} \leq \lim_{j \to \infty} \frac{a_{k(j)}}{a_{k(j+1)}}$ for any sequence $a_{k(j)}$.

Comment: @EwanDelanoy check again, it's the limit **as n** (not m) goes to $\infty$.

Comment: Also, I think your weaker question is more difficult.

Comment: You're right, my first comment was wrong. I see another problem though :

Comment: What's the other problem?

Comment: I think there might be a subsequence convergeing to 1 without the whole sequence convergeing to 1. I'm working on it

Comment: See my latest edit, which hopefully addresses your concerns.

Comment: I'm convinced now, but I still think your presentation is complicated. I would say it as follows : a subsequence obviously grows faster than the initial sequence, so the growth (i.e. the limsup of $a_{k+1}/a_k$) of a subsequences is always larger than the growth of the initial sequence. Since we have subsequence of growth $\leq 1+\varepsilon$ for every $\varepsilon >0$, the initial sequence must have growth $1$.

Comment: My presentation is formal.  Your presentation is intuitive, and is understandable to anyone who shares that intuition.  I'd imagine that if I posted it your way, someone would object that the first fact wasn't so "obvious" after all.

Answer (score 1):

See, how many numbers $a_k$ are there below some huge $N$? At least this includes all of those for which $2^n\le{N\over2}$ and $3^m\le{N\over2}$ (and probably more), which is already $O(\log^2N)$, which pretty much forbids the existence of a limit > 1.

Comment: OK, I edited it. The limit can't be more than 1; now we must prove that it _exists_.

Comment: I see now. Thank you, +1